MultipartFormDataInput upload with non ASCII file name. Quarkus
I faced some difficulties to upload file with non ASCII file name.
Part of the code is:
package org.example;

import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.MultipartForm;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.InputPart;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput;

@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void hello(@MultipartForm MultipartFormDataInput formDataInput) {
        Map<String, List<InputPart>> dataMap = formDataInput.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputs = dataMap.get("attachment");
        System.out.println("Data map: " + dataMap);
        System.out.println("Data inputs: " + inputs);
    }
}

Step to reproduce:

Create both files with different names and one extension to compare: Новый_документ.docx and   New_document.docx.

Once both are created try to upload it using postman with attachment key




Debug the data and have a look that formDataInput.getFormDataMap() method called dataMap  returns really strange key that is encoded with UTF-8 and it's cut because it has .doc instead of .docx. I suppose the key of the map is filename*=UTF-8 value that is taken from Content-Disposition header.

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename="Новый_документ.docx"; filename*=UTF-8''%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.docx


Inputs is null.


Do the same with ASCII file name New_document.docx. And pay attention at the same map. For now there is expected key and Inputs isn't null



So, my problem is: when I try to upload any file with non ASCII file name I can't get attachment key from formDataInput.getFormDataMap() method result.
I tried to use several approaches to solve it:

Was added

@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA + ";charset=utf-8")

instead of
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)


Was added ContainerRequestFilter implementation:

package org.example;

import static org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.InputPart.DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY;
import static org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.InputPart.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_PROPERTY;

import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
public class ContainerRequestFilterImpl implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.setProperty(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_PROPERTY, "multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8");
        requestContext.setProperty(DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY, "utf-8");
    }
}

I have no idea already what I've done wrong and how to solve it
Used:
io.quarkus:quarkus-bom:3.13.0
org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:6.2.9.Final

UPD
As result I did it manually. I parse Content-Disposition from each InputPart of formDataInput.getFormDataMap() method result manually to create fixed form data map with correct key-value

Which java version are you using ? With Java 17 you have to set the file.encoding jvm param to UTF-8. And if this doesn’t solve, then you have to manually convert that string to utf-8 with a charset.

I had same problem. Everything started after moving from Java 8 to Java 21. To make everything work you need to add filename with standard english chars. I'm sending requests with libcurl to Java backend and the solution lies in curl_mime_filename. It will override attached filename. For example curl_mime_filename(part,"image.jpg");
